# Ignorar propriedade Automapper

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

Estou usando o AutoMapper versão 7.
Preciso ignorar uma propriedade que tem na classe result e não tem classe source. Conforme abaixo.

```cs
public class Contrato
{
    public string Id{get;set;}
    public string Nome {get;set;}
}

public class ContratoDto
{
    public string Id{get;set;}
    public string Nome {get;set;}
    public string Descricao{get;set;}
}
```

Se eu uso o Mapper conforme abaixo, ele me dá o erro que tem Propriedade não mapeada.

```
CreateMap<Contrato, ContratoDto>();
var c = _contratoRepositorio.BuscarContrato(requisicao.CodigoContrato).FirstOrDefault();

Mapper.Map<Contrato, ContratoDto>(c));
```

*Unmapped Property: Descricao*

Como eu posso ignorar a propriedade no Dto que não existe e nem vai existir dentro da model?

Answer (score 1):

É possível ignorar propriedades com o `.ForMember(p => p.Propriedade, x=> x.Ignore())`

Ficando assim:

```
CreateMap<Contrato, ContratoDto>().ForMember(p => p.Descricao, x=> x.Ignore());
```

Em uma pesquisa no SO achei essa resposta onde é dada uma [Solução via método de extensão](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16808867/6200920), porém não cheguei a testar.

Segue o código:

```
public static IMappingExpression<TSource, TDestination> Ignore<TSource, TDestination>(
    this IMappingExpression<TSource, TDestination> map,
    Expression<Func<TDestination, object>> selector)
{
    map.ForMember(selector, config => config.Ignore());
    return map;
}

Mapper.CreateMap<JsonRecord, DatabaseRecord>()
        .Ignore(record => record.Field)
        .Ignore(record => record.AnotherField)
        .Ignore(record => record.Etc);
```

Comment: o .ForMember(p => p.Propriedade, x=> x.Ignore()) não funciona pra mim. abri essa pergunta justamente por estressar o uso do .ForMember e não funcionar.

Comment: Tentou com o `ForSourceMember`?

Comment: @ThiagoHenrique pode explicar o que não funcionou? acho que na versão 7 em diante não se usa `.Ignore()`, mas sim `.DoNotValidate()`, faça um teste e posso colocar em mais detalhes

Comment: @Barbetta tentei os dois. nenhum funcionou.

Comment: Encontrei a solução "temporária" que por hora me ajudou, mas não sei se é a opção correta. 
```cfg.ValidateInlineMaps = false; ``` no Initialize do Mapper. Neste caso ele deixou de validar tudo.

Comment: @RicardoPontual essa opção não tem disponível na minha versão. Tem é o Ignore mesmo.

Comment: @ThiagoHenrique o `DoNotValidate` está disponível a partir da versão 8, fui confirmar :) http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/8.0-Upgrade-Guide.html

Comment: @RicardoPontual boa. Valeu Ricardo.